# Correct memory order to prevent potential deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, wait, stdatomic

The below program has 4 threads that run sequentially. Since each of them is `wait()`ing on its own `std::atomic_bool` flag to be notified in order to resume its operation, it cannot check its own `std::stop_token` and thus needs to be unblocked by another thread (preferably the parent thread) to then check the token and quit if a stop has been requested.

How can this be achieved?

The below solution came to my mind. I have thought about some edge cases and things that could go wrong but everything seems okay so far (also have done some tests). But I am not certain about it.

Here's an MRE ([live](https://godbolt.org/z/efv4j8qq8)):

```
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <stop_token>
#include <functional>
#include <exception>
#include <chrono>
#include <array>
#include <span>
#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/chrono.h>


struct payload_t
{
    int data;
};

struct message_t
{
    payload_t payload;
};

constexpr auto iteration_count { 20uz };


void handle_thread_exceptions( const std::span<const std::exception_ptr> caught_exceptions ) noexcept
{
    for ( const auto& ex_ptr : caught_exceptions )
    {
        if ( ex_ptr != nullptr )
        {
            try
            {
                std::rethrow_exception( ex_ptr );
            }
            catch ( const std::exception& ex )
            {
                fmt::print( "{}\n", ex.what( ) );
            }
        }
    }
}


void first_func( const std::stop_token stop_tkn, std::atomic_bool& stop_flag,
                 payload_t& payload_IN_OUT,
                 std::atomic_bool& input_data_flag,
                 std::atomic_bool& output_data_flag,
                 std::exception_ptr& ex_ptr )
{
    auto counter { 0uz };

    while ( true )
    {
        try
        {
            input_data_flag.wait( false, std::memory_order_acquire );
            input_data_flag.store( false, std::memory_order_relaxed );
            if ( stop_tkn.stop_requested( ) ) break;

            if ( counter == iteration_count )
            {
                stop_flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
                stop_flag.notify_one( );
                continue;
            }

            fmt::print( "First Func before: {}\n", payload_IN_OUT.data );
            payload_IN_OUT.data += 1;
            ++counter;
            fmt::print( "First Func after: {}\n", payload_IN_OUT.data );
            output_data_flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
            output_data_flag.notify_one( );
        }
        catch ( ... )
        {
            stop_flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
            stop_flag.notify_one( );
            ex_ptr = std::current_exception( );
        }
    }
}

void second_func( const std::stop_token stop_tkn, std::atomic_bool& stop_flag,
                  const payload_t& payload_IN, std::atomic_bool& input_data_flag,
                  message_t& message_OUT, std::atomic_bool& output_data_flag,
                  std::exception_ptr& ex_ptr )
{
    while ( true )
    {
        try
        {
            input_data_flag.wait( false, std::memory_order_acquire );
            input_data_flag.store( false, std::memory_order_relaxed );
            if ( stop_tkn.stop_requested( ) ) break;

            fmt::print( "Second Func before: {}\n", message_OUT.payload.data );
            message_OUT.payload = payload_IN;
            fmt::print( "Second Func after: {}\n", message_OUT.payload.data );
            output_data_flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
            output_data_flag.notify_one( );
        }
        catch ( ... )
        {
            stop_flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
            stop_flag.notify_one( );
            ex_ptr = std::current_exception( );
        }
    }
}

void third_func( const std::stop_token stop_tkn, std::atomic_bool& stop_flag,
                 message_t& message_IN_OUT,
                 std::atomic_bool& input_data_flag,
                 std::atomic_bool& output_data_flag,
                 std::exception_ptr& ex_ptr )
{
    while ( true )
    {
        try
        {
            input_data_flag.wait( false, std::memory_order_acquire );
            input_data_flag.store( false, std::memory_order_relaxed );
            if ( stop_tkn.stop_requested( ) ) break;

            fmt::print( "Third Func before: {}\n", message_IN_OUT.payload.data );
            message_IN_OUT.payload.data += 2;
            fmt::print( "Third Func after: {}\n", message_IN_OUT.payload.data );
            output_data_flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
            output_data_flag.notify_one( );
        }
        catch ( ... )
        {
            stop_flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
            stop_flag.notify_one( );
            ex_ptr = std::current_exception( );
        }
    }
}

void fourth_func( const std::stop_token stop_tkn, std::atomic_bool& stop_flag,
                  const message_t& message_IN, std::atomic_bool& input_data_flag,
                  payload_t& payload_OUT, std::atomic_bool& output_data_flag,
                  std::exception_ptr& ex_ptr )
{
    while ( true )
    {
        try
        {
            input_data_flag.wait( false, std::memory_order_acquire );
            input_data_flag.store( false, std::memory_order_relaxed );
            if ( stop_tkn.stop_requested( ) ) break;

            fmt::print( "Fourth Func before: {}\n", payload_OUT.data );
            payload_OUT = message_IN.payload;
            fmt::print( "Fourth Func after: {}\n", payload_OUT.data );
            output_data_flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
            output_data_flag.notify_one( );
        }
        catch ( ... )
        {
            stop_flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
            stop_flag.notify_one( );
            ex_ptr = std::current_exception( );
        }
    }
}

int main( )
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    const auto start { time_point_cast<microseconds>( steady_clock::now( ) ) };

    constexpr auto thread_count { 4uz };
    std::array<std::exception_ptr, thread_count> caught_exceptions { };

    {
    std::stop_source stop_src { std::nostopstate };
    std::atomic_bool stop_flag { };

    std::array<std::atomic_bool, thread_count> flags { };
    auto& [ payload_flag, altered_payload_flag, message_flag, altered_message_flag ] { flags };

    std::array<std::jthread, thread_count> threads { };
    auto& [ first_thread, second_thread, third_thread, fourth_thread ] { threads };

    try
    {
        // throw std::runtime_error { "Oh!" };
        stop_src = std::stop_source { };

        payload_t payload { 0 };
        first_thread = std::jthread { first_func, stop_src.get_token( ), std::ref( stop_flag ),
                                      std::ref( payload ),
                                      std::ref( payload_flag ), std::ref( altered_payload_flag ),
                                      std::ref( caught_exceptions[ 0 ] ) };

        message_t message { };
        second_thread = std::jthread { second_func, stop_src.get_token( ), std::ref( stop_flag ),
                                       std::cref( payload ), std::ref( altered_payload_flag ),
                                       std::ref( message ), std::ref( message_flag ),
                                       std::ref( caught_exceptions[ 1 ] ) };

        third_thread = std::jthread { third_func, stop_src.get_token( ), std::ref( stop_flag ),
                                      std::ref( message ),
                                      std::ref( message_flag ), std::ref( altered_message_flag ),
                                      std::ref( caught_exceptions[ 2 ] ) };

        fourth_thread = std::jthread { fourth_func, stop_src.get_token( ), std::ref( stop_flag ),
                                       std::cref( message ), std::ref( altered_message_flag ),
                                       std::ref( payload ), std::ref( payload_flag ),
                                       std::ref( caught_exceptions[ 3 ] ) };
        
        payload_flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
        payload_flag.notify_one( );
    }
    catch ( const std::exception& ex )
    {
        stop_flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
        stop_flag.notify_one( );
        fmt::print( "{}\n", ex.what( ) );
    }

    stop_flag.wait( false, std::memory_order_acquire );
    stop_src.request_stop( );

    for ( auto& flag : flags )
    {
        flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
        flag.notify_one( );
    }

    }

    handle_thread_exceptions( caught_exceptions );

    const auto end { time_point_cast<microseconds>( steady_clock::now( ) ) };
    fmt::print( "{}\n", end - start );
}
```

The way this works is, an exception may be thrown in each worker thread that is caught by its catch clause. Or nothing goes wrong and eventually, the first worker thread determines the work is done (i.e. `if ( counter == iteration_count )`). Inside the catch block, the exception is handled and a common flag (i.e. `stop_flag`) is set and notified in order to awake the parent thread (in this case the `main` thread) which `wait()`s indefinitely until it receives this notification from one of the four worker threads (due to the end of their tasks normally, or due to an exception being thrown in one of them). It then requests a stop and manually sets and notifies all the flags of all four worker threads (in the last for loop) in order to unblock them so they can progress and check their stop tokens and break out of their `while (true)` loops and return.

======================================================================

Now the ***important question*** is what *memory order* tags should be used throughout the program to prevent any deadlocks? I have actually discovered that in order to not have a specific and rare deadlock, the below order must be preserved:

```
input_data_flag.store( false, std::memory_order_relaxed ); // must be executed first
if ( stop_tkn.stop_requested( ) ) break;
```

And also here:

```
stop_src.request_stop( ); // must be executed first

for ( auto& flag : flags )
{
    flag.store( true, std::memory_order_release );
    flag.notify_one( );
}
```

These most likely ensure that rare deadlocks can't occur. But the use of `std::memory_order_relaxed` makes me feel like the order might be arbitrarily messed up and cause a dealock.

And finally, is the above solution a good way of solving this problem at all (i.e. is it an efficient way of notifying a number of `std::jthread`s to quit and return when they're in a blocking atomic operation (e.g. [`std::atomic<T>::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait)) like the above code)? And could there be any sort of issues in the above program? Like potential UB? Hidden deadlocks? etc.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253422/discussion-on-question-by-digito-evo-correct-memory-order-to-prevent-potential-d); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.